# Set Incremental Values from Array of Items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to update the multiple documents in MongoDB and set the value of the element in an increasing order?

I have got the document as follows

```
{
   "_id" :  ObjectId("5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920d")   
}
{
   "_id" :  ObjectId("5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920f")  
}
{
   "_id" :  ObjectId("5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920c")  
}
```

How can I update the whole documents with a single query so that I can have a new element called "order" in every single field in an increasing order as below

```
{
   "_id" :  ObjectId("5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920d"),
   "order": 1
}
{
   "_id" :  ObjectId("5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920f"),
    "order": 2  
}
{
   "_id" :  ObjectId("5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920c"),
    "order": 3  
}
```

Currently I am using the following way to solve the problem

```
   for(let i = 0; i <= req.body.id.length;i++) {

            const queryOpts = {
                _id: ObjectId(req.body.id[i])
            };

            const updateOpts = {
                $set: {
                    'order': i + 1
                }
            };

        const dataRes = await req.db.collection('GalleryImage').updateOne(queryOpts, updateOpts); 

         if(i === req.body.id.length-1) {
                return commonHelper.sendResponseMessage(res, dataRes, {
                    _id: req.body.id
                }, moduleConfig.message.updateGalleryOrder);


            }
```

If there any better way than this so that it would not be the expensive operation if there are large number of documents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to construct the statement:

```
try {
  let response = await req.db.collection('GalleryImage').bulkWrite(
    req.body.id.map((_id,order) => 
      ({ updateOne: {
       filter: { _id: ObjectId(_id) },
       update: {
         $set: { order: order+1 }
       }
      }})
    )
  );
 } catch(e) {
   // deal with any errors
 }
```

`Array.map()` has the "index" of the array element being processed within it's second function argument. So simply use that to get the `order` and set that on all statements.

Rather than writing/responding with the database `n` times, this only needs happen **"once"**.

There is no other way to get a "sequence" other than introducing it yourself, but at least we can do it with **"one"** write this way instead of several. Note also to "trap your possible errors" when using `async/await` syntax.

---

#### Example listing

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID: ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

const data = [
  "5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920d",
  "5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920f",
  "5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920c"
];

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
(async function() {

  try {

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
    let db = client.db('test');

    // Set up
    await db.collection('gallery').removeMany({});
    await db.collection('gallery').insertMany(
      data.map(_id => ({ _id: ObjectId(_id) }))
    );

    // Update with indexes
    let response = await db.collection('gallery').bulkWrite(
      data.map((_id,idx) =>
        ({
          updateOne: {
            filter: { _id: ObjectId(_id) },
            update: { $set: { order: idx+1 } }
          }
        })
      )
    );

    log({ response });

    let items = await db.collection('gallery').find().toArray();
    log({ items });

    client.close();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

And the output

```
{
  "response": {
    "ok": 1,
    "writeErrors": [],
    "writeConcernErrors": [],
    "insertedIds": [],
    "nInserted": 0,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nMatched": 3,
    "nModified": 3,
    "nRemoved": 0,
    "upserted": [],
    "lastOp": {
      "ts": "6563535160225038345",
      "t": 18
    }
  }
}
{
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": "5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920d",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920f",
      "order": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "5b162a31dfaf342dc44c920c",
      "order": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Clearly shows `nMatched: 3` and `nModified: 3` just as is expected.

Comment: It does not give the response as ***result: { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }*** Can't I get the response in that format ?

Comment: @chyangba [`BulkWriteOpResult`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#~BulkWriteOpResult) is the type of response you get. Because it's a "batch" then there are different considerations than the simple "singular" response form. See the link, and look at the link for `bulkWrite()` given in the answer already.

Comment: @chyangba I don't know what you're doing wrong, but I just added an example listing which clearly shows the `nMatched` and `nModified` from the correct `BulkWriteOpResult` just like I told you was there.

Comment: The title of the question as you have edited is not what it mean to be. Set Incremental Values from Array of Items